# Repeating control n times and binding each instance

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, binding

I am trying to figure out a less messy way of repeating a control *n* times, depending on a bound model's property value. The first *m* of *n* controls should be displayed differently however, whereas *m* is bound to a different property of the ViewModel. To illustrate the problem, consider I am having a ViewModel like this (*n* being `Display` and *m* `Checked` here):

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public int Display { get; set; }
    public int Checked { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

For `Display = 5, Checked = 3`, the view should render something along the lines of:

```
(X) (X) (X) ( ) ( )
```

Each `(X)` and `( )` should be instances of the same child view type. Now, when the user clicks on the fifth (last) control, `Checked` should be set to 5 and the View would now display

```
(X) (X) (X) (X) (X)
```

Now I could achieve this by hooking up a few event handlers and programmatically adding and binding `( )` instances whenever `Display` changes. I do wonder though if there is a more concise, lessy messy method to achieve this.

Comment: Not quite, but its mechanics would be similar. It also differs from rating controls in regards to its scale: it can and will change the maximum value during runtime depending on external circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the ViewModel as a model of the View. So if you want to show a collection of items in the view you have to provide that collection on the ViewModel.

In this case add a collection to the ViewModel that changes when the value for Display and Checked changes. Then bind an ItemsControl to the collection and provide an ItemTemplate for the items.

Comment: This solution is so simple, elegant and obvious that it slipped right by my head :)